# How do I convert an abstract class into an interface?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I have a java program which uses arraylists - these arraylists store 'variables' where 'variables' is an abstract class.

Now, to save memory, I want to use a java library called HugeCollections-VanillaJava- however this library requires an interface to be defined.

How do I convert the abstract class into an interface? What rules/restrictions do I have to follow, to correctly perform the conversion?

Finally, is it possible for me to use my abstract class with minimal code changes, so that the library that requires an interface, also works correctly? Ideally I would like not to change the abstract class at all...Is this possible?

Comment: Could you show us some of your code? Your questions are a bit confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how do I convert an abstract class into an interface?

1. Make a copy of the abstract class source file.
2. Change "class" to "interface" in the initial declaration.
3. Change the name (optionally, depends on what you're doing).
4. Remove the bodies of any methods that are implemented by the class.
5. Remove the word "abstract" from the other ones.
6. Remove all private and protected members.
7. Remove all constructors.
8. Remove the keyword "public" from the public members.

If you had any code you removed (implemented methods, private or protected stuff), have your original abstract class implement your interface and leave that stuff there.

(Incomplete) Example:

`Foo` as an abstract class:

```
public abstact class Foo
{
    private int bar;

    public static final int SOME_CONSTANT = 42;

    public Foo(b) {
        this.bar = b;
    }

    public abstract void doSomething(String s);

    protected int doSomethingElse() {
        return this.bar * 2;
    }
}
```

`Foo` as an interface:

```
public interface Foo
{
    int SOME_CONSTANT = 42;

    void doSomething(String s);
}
```

In my case, as I did have some stuff the old `Foo` did, I'd probably have `AbstractFoo` or something:

```
public abstact class AbstractFoo implements Foo
{
    private int bar;

    public Foo(b) {
        this.bar = b;
    }

    public abstract void doSomething(String s);

    protected int doSomethingElse() {
        return this.bar * 2;
    }
}
```

...so that an implementation could use it as a starting point if desired (although with that `private` `bar` in there, it doesn't make a lot of sense).

Answer (score 3):

Pattern [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) might help you.

Imagine, you're have to use **SomeClass** as **TargetInterface**

```
public abstract class SomeClass {
       // some code here
     public abstract void someMethod();
}

public interface TargetInterface {
     public void someMethodBlaBla();
}
```

And they have different signatures of methods - **someMethod()** and **someMethodBlaBla()**.

So you're might create such adapter class:

```
public class Adapter implements TargetInterface {
   private SomeClass adaptee;

   public Adapter( SomeClass adaptee ) {
       this.adaptee = adaptee;
   }

   public void someMethodBlaBla() {
       this.adaptee.someMethod();
   }

   //delegate all calls to adaptee
}
```

and somewhere in code you might use both - adapter and instance of abstract class, without interference on current code:

```
SomeClass abstractClassInstance = ... //get instance of your abstract class
TargetInterface targetInterfaceInstance = new Adapter( abstractClassInstance );
```

Answer (score 0):

If abstract class does not define any concrete methods, you can even use regular expression for that. From:

```
public abstract class Abstract {
  public abstract void method();
  //...
}
```

to:

```
public interface Interface {
  void method();
  //...
}
```

`public abstract` modifiers are implicit for interfaces. If the `abstract` class *does* define some methods (not all methods are `abstract`) or have some fields this can't be done (at least easily).

Comment: Don't forget about attributes in abstract class